# Silverstripe 3.1 - One player has many teams

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm trying to create a Team List like this.

TeamHolder - for all teams. Has Teampages as children

TeamPage - description and image of the team. And also an has_one relation to TeamMember(Dataobject)

TeamMember - has the members. here you also should be able to define in which teams the player is. here's my code for this. But i don't know how i can make a has_many relation to my team pages, so that you can choose multiple teams for one player. has anyone a solution for this?

http://www.sspaste.com/paste/show/526422c0d33bc

thx in advance

Comment: The team member has multiple teams? Shouldn't the team member have only one team, and a team can have multiple team members? If so, `TeamPage` would have a `has_many` relationship to `TeamMember` and `TeamMember` would have a `has_one` relationship to `TeamPage`. If a team member can have multiple teams, and a team can have multiple team members, then you want a `many_many` relationship between to the two. So `TeamPage` would have a `many_many` link to `TeamMember` and `TeamMember` would have a `belongs_many_many` link back to `TeamPage`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want 1 Player (TeamMember) to be in multiple Teams, and Teams to have multiple Players, you need a many_many. If you use has_many here, then the Team would have a PlayerID, which means there can only be 1 Player in each team.

```
class TeamPage extends Page {
    private static $many_many = array('TeamMembers' => 'TeamMember');
    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root', Tab::create('MembersTab', 'Team Members'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.MembersTab', GridField::create('TeamMembers', 'The Team Members', $this->TeamMembers(), GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create());
        return $fields;
    }
}
class TeamMember extends DataObject {
    private static $belongs_many_many = array('Teams' => 'TeamPage');
    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = FieldList::create();
        if (!$this->isInDB()) {
            // if the TeamMember has not been saved yet, display a message that it needs to be saved before teams can be assigned
            $fields->push(ReadOnlyField::create('Teams', '', 'Save to assign Teams'));
        } else {
            $config = GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create();
            // if you don't want the "add a new team" button on this grid, you can remove that with the following line:
            // $config->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldAddNewButton');
            $fields->push(GridField::create('Teams', 'Team this Member is in', $this->Teams(), $config);
        }
        return $fields;
    }
}
```

**NOTE here that I used `GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor` instead of `GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor` which adds a `GridFieldAddExistingAutocompleter` to your gridfield that lets you link objects.**

Comment: Hi, this seems to work pretty good :) But is there a way to remove the "add teampage" button when adding a new member?

Comment: what "add teampage" button? can you make a screenshot of that?

Comment: If you add a new member, than you've got this option. http://x04.img-up.net/Unbenannt-9546.jpg

Comment: you can remove that button from the gridfield by calling `->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldAddNewButton')` on the gridfield config, I updated the code example in my answer to include that as a comment

Comment: Works! :)

But there's another error. If the Dataobject with the new member isn't saved. and you want to add a team relation than you get a server error. here's my console output http://x75.img-up.net/Unbenannt-2364.jpg

Comment: And another question, i tried to get a list of the teams a member is in, into the $summary_fields. I tried it with 'Teams.Title' but the result was only an empty field. Is this possible?

Comment: yes it is possible, but with a custom method in summary fields. but that's sort of another question, would you mind opening a new question for that? the title could be something like this: "display titles from many_many relation in GridField"

Comment: about the error, my mistake, of course you can not assign teams if the member is not saved yet, I have updated the code in my answer to check `$this->isInDB()` before displaying the gridfield

Comment: thx for fixing it and here's the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523983/display-titles-from-many-many-relation-in-gridfield-silverstripe

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19524951/silverstripe-3-1-many-many-relation-unlink-and-delete-entries also another question relating to this topic. Perhaps you can help me out there too