# Silverstripe 3.1 - many_many relation - unlink and delete entries

Tags: silverstripe

Normally there's only a unlink function for the entries in a many_many relation grid field. But that's messy.

How can I also add an delete option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use:

```
$config->addComponent(new GridFieldDeleteAction(false));
```

which will add a delete button. The `false` argument specify that it is a *delete* button not *unlink*. `$config` is your `GridFieldConfig` instance.